# better way of handling django query

Tags: python, django

I have the following models.

```
class Model1(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()

class Model2(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   model1 = models.ForeignKey(model1)

class Model3(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   model2 = models.ForeignKey(model2)
   flag = models.BooleanField(blank=False)
```

so my display should be like, `Model2.name` and `Model1.name` on the listing page.
conditions are: I should only display `Model2` instances which at least have one `Model3.flag = True`

So right now I am getting all the `Model2` objects in the list and iterate over `Model3`. 
I am not able to properly use `select_related()` for the model.
Can any one help.

thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you able to "properly use select_related()"? Seems like the best way here.

Comment: Please improve your code as suggested in edit.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
qs = Model2.objects.filter(model3__flag=True).select_related('model1').distinct()
for m2 in qs:
    print m2.model1.name, m2.name

# only fetch the names, 
# this works if you treat duplicated ('name', 'model1__name') tuples same and show them once.
qs = qs.values('model1__name', 'name')
for x in qs:
    print x['model1__name'], x['name']
```